# Creating an array of toys in javascript

Tags: javascript

I create an online store with toys for children. I want to write the whole list of toys in the array in javascript, I tried to do it in the following way.

```js
var toys = [
     {'cars': [
        0 : ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image'],
        1 : ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image'],
        2 : ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image']
     ]},
     
     {'tractors': [
        0 : ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image'],
        1 : ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image'],
        2 : ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image']
     ]}
];

document.write(toys[cars][0][name]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `toys` is invalid array of object!

Comment: [Your syntax for the inner arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax) is wrong, hence the uncaught syntaxerror

Comment: `name` is not a property, but an element of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using invalid JavaScript. Arrays are not declared with their indexes like in PHP. Just list them within brackets (`[`, `]`).

```js
var toys = {
  'cars': [
    { 'name': 'HERE', 'type': '', 'color': '', 'image': '' },
    { 'name': '', 'type': '', 'color': '', 'image': '' },
    { 'name': '', 'type': '', 'color': '', 'image': '' }
  ],
  'tractors': [
    { 'name': '', 'type': '', 'color': '', 'image': '' },
    { 'name': '', 'type': '', 'color': '', 'image': '' },
    { 'name': '', 'type': '', 'color': '', 'image': '' }
  ]
};

document.write(toys['cars'][0]['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using document.write is a bad practice I suggest you to replace the content in an element...
You have syntax... errors that were corrected.

```js
var toys = [
     {'cars': [
         ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image'],
         ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image'],
         ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image']
     ]},
     
     {'tractors': [
        ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image'],
        ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image'],
        ['name', 'type', 'color', 'image']
     ]}
];

var el = document.getElementById('toys');

el.innerHTML= toys[0]['cars'][0];
```

```html
<div id="toys"></div>
```